# Histogram using to data tables (SQL query)

Tags: mysql, sql, graph, histogram

I want to make a histogram of the number of comments per user in January 2019 (including the once that haven't commented)

The tables I'm working with look like this:

| id | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Jose |
| 2 | Pedro |
| 3 | Juan |
| 4 | Sofia |

| user_id | Comment | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Hello | 2018-10-02 11:00:03 |
| 3 | Didn't Like it | 2018-06-02 11:00:03 |
| 1 | Not so bad | 2018-10-22 11:00:03 |
| 2 | Trash | 2018-7-21 11:00:03 |

I think I'm overcomplicating it. But here is my try:

```
#Here I'm counting how much comments are per person that have commented. 

CREATE TABLE aux AS
SELECT user_id, COUNT(user_id)
FROM Undostres
GROUP BY user_id;

#With the following code, I end up with a table with the missing values (ids that haven't commented) 

CREATE TABLE Test AS
SELECT DISTINCT user_id +1
FROM aux
WHERE user_id + 1 NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT user_id FROM aux);

ALTER TABLE Test RENAME COLUMN user_id +1 TO  ;
INSERT INTO Undostres (user_id) 
SELECT user_id  FROM Test;
```

It returns an error when I try to rename user_id+1 with other name. So I can't keep going.

Any suggestions would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it this way:

```
CREATE TABLE aux AS
SELECT Users.user_id, COUNT(Undostres.user_id) AS count
FROM Users 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Undostres USING (user_id)
GROUP BY Users.user_id;
```

I am assuming you have a table `Users` that enumerates all your users, whether they have made any comments or not. The LEFT OUTER JOIN helps in this case, because if there are no comments for a given user, the user is still part of the result, and the COUNT is 0.